# how to navigate between views with buttons in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-button

I want to generate the function to my button to be able to make that when I press it it goes to a new view but I do not know how I already have more than 3 hours trying

[image]

Comment: Btw please post your code as text, not an image

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple problems:

1. If you want to use [programmatic navigation](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-programmatic-navigation-in-swiftui) (using a custom button), you'll need an `@State` to control whether the `NavigationLink` is active or not.
2. `NavigationLink` needs to be somewhere inside a `NavigationView`.
3. You also need a `VStack`, because `NavigationView` should only wrap around a single View.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresenting = false /// 1.
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView { /// 2.
            VStack { /// 3.
                Button("comenzar") {
                    isPresenting = true
                }
                //        .buttonStyle(fillesRundedCornerButtonStyle())
                
                NavigationLink(destination: HolaView(), isActive: $isPresenting) { EmptyView() }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HolaView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hola, como estas?")
    }
}
```